# Defining Max Value for Breaks in Symbology instead of data driven Breaks

Tags: qgis, symbology, break

I'm mapping positivity rates per Zip code. I have four main race counts in my attribute table and I duplicate this shapefile in order to create 4 different map layouts; White positivity per Zip code, Black positivity per Zip code, Hispanic positivity per Zip code and Asian positivity per Zip code.

When I use graduated symbology and classify my values by selecting the related field on my attribute table, QGIS sets my max value to that field's max value. So when I put these into my layout it looks like each race has the maximum positivity in some areas while in reality their positivity rate is much lower.

I'm trying to map these values (rates) in a way where the max value is 100 across all 4 layers representing %100 positivity and map races accordingly.

I.e if in zip code 55555 whites have %20 blacks have %30 hispanics have %40 and asians have %50 and when I classify this layers in whites' layer my color that represent the maximum value (let's say red) shows up completely red but the same red is assigned to %30 for blacks, %40 for hispanics and %40 for asians. But I'm trying to map these so %20 for whites, blacks, hispanics and asians are exactly the same color.

Is there a way to achieve this without changing classification numbers by hand every time I click on classify?